# Equivalent C++ timezone conversion?

Tags: python, c++

In python, I am doing the following to convert between timezones.  It also takes care of daylight savings adjustments, so I don't have to worry about that.  What is the equivalent way to do this in C++, without having to worry about daylight savings?

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

# Create timezones
londontz = timezone("Europe/London")
nyctz = timezone("US/Eastern")

# Set today as 5pm London time
today = datetime.date.today()
time = datetime.time(17, 0, 0)
londondt = londontz.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(today, time))

# Convert the London close time to NYC time (this will auto-adjust for DST)
nycdt = londondt.astimezone(nyctz)
```

Comment: Sure.  Get a date/time library and let it deal with it for you.

Comment: Have a look at localtime and tzset.

Comment: If you are developing using .NET look into the TimeZoneInfo class for handling datetime.

Comment: I can only use standard libraries unfortunately

Comment: @holtc There is no standard C++ library to do this, as far as I'm aware. I mean that this functionality doesn't just come with C++. You will either need to write it yourself or find a 3rd party library to do it.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't include this sort of functionality in the standard library (yet, anyway).

Nonetheless, you definitely want to leave this to a library if at all possible. That library, in turn, will delegate a whole lot of the real work to a database, since it's essentially impossible to model everything correctly as an actual algorithm.

Given what you're asking for, [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) would be the obvious first choice.

Comment: gotcha, thanks.  I'd only be able to use standard libraries

Comment: @holtc Five bucks say's Howard Hinnant is sticking as close to the standard libraries as reasonably possible. Even if you can't directly use his library for some reason you can probably get ideas from it.

Comment: @holtc: In that case, you're pretty much stuck with duplicating his library. I'd work hard to get permission to use his code instead. This functionality doesn't exist in the C++ standard library at the present time. If/when it's added to the standard library,chances are *very* good that the interface will be based on his library (in case you're not aware of it, Howard used to chair the C++ committee's library working group, and is still on the committee).

Comment: Or use Boost.Date_Time.

Comment: One advantage Howard Hinnant's library has over boost date_time is that Howard's takes the full history of the IANA timezone database into account, and makes it easy to keep up with the latest IANA database versions (it changes 6-9 times a year).

Answer (score 2):

Fwiw, here is the syntax that [Howard Hinnant's library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) (MIT open-source license) would use for this problem:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    // Set today as 5pm London time
    auto londontz = locate_zone("Europe/London");
    auto today = floor<days>(make_zoned(londontz,
                                        system_clock::now()).get_local_time());
    auto londondt = make_zoned(londontz, today + 17h);

    // Convert the London close time to NYC time (this will auto-adjust for DST)
    auto nycdt = make_zoned("US/Eastern", londondt);

    // print it out
    std::cout << "London  : " << londondt << '\n';
    std::cout << "New York: " << nycdt    << '\n';
}
```

The first thing to do is to find "`today`" according to "Europe/London".  This is done by getting the current time, translating that to the current time in London, and then truncating that current local time to the current local date (with `floor<days>()`).

Once `today` is established, adding 17h to it is very easy.

And then constructing `nycdt` from `londondt` is also very easy.

This just output for me:

```
London  : 2016-12-13 17:00:00 GMT
New York: 2016-12-13 12:00:00 EST
```

I note that a strict translation of the original code defines `today` as the computer's local date.  That is also possible:

```
auto today = floor<days>(make_zoned(current_zone(),
                                    system_clock::now()).get_local_time());
```

That is, use `current_zone()` in place of a specific timezone.  But my best guess is that use of `current_zone()` to determine the date is actually a logic error in the example.  This library helps in finding such logic errors and easily correcting them.

Solutions involving only the std::lib drop down to a pre-multithreading C API designed several decades ago.  You have to change the computer's timezone to London, do conversions between that local and UTC, and then change the computer's timezone to NY, and do conversions between *that* local and UTC.  Not only is that error-prone, it isn't thread safe if you have multiple threads depending on what the current local timezone is.  Additionally there is no truly standard way to even specify "Europe/London" and "US/Eastern" with the old C api.  You can do it with POSIX extensions.